# Android XML Layout is not fitting for most of devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I am working on a Android project in android studio. In main activity layout the layout doesn't fit for every smart phone. Please help me in this case.

Here is the XML code of main playout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ml.microlion.development.fmmahanama.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/fmmahanama_banner2"
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:text="Play Stream"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_playstream"
                android:layout_weight="0.51"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored"
                android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorPressedHighlight"
                android:elevation="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/adbar_prev"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="66dp">

            <Button
                android:text="Go To Website"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_website"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="Feedback"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_feedback"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="Share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_share"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In default Device in Editor i use Nexus 4. It is ok on editor. But when I run it  in my galaxy j7 and galaxy dous 2 i can see that layout doesn't fit.

Comment: can you please add a screen shot

Comment: you have to use "layout_weight" properly. If you just provide the screenshot I may help you to modify the XML code according to your requirement. :)